# "react-native-fade-in-view" causes "Cannot read property 'func' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new in react native and I need to use "react-native-fade-in-view" in my project. However, as I used `import FadeInView from 'react-native-fade-in-view';` in my project, the following error is shown:

> Cannot read property 'func' of undefined

As I deleted my module folder and applied the yarn command on the project to refresh the folder, the following warning shown:

> yarn install v1.3.2 warning ../../../package.json: No license field
>
> [1/4] Resolving packages... [2/4] Fetching packages... info
>
> fsevents@1.1.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
>
> info "fsevents@1.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed
>
> compatibility check. Excluding it from installation. [3/4] Linking
>
> dependencies... warning " > react-native-fade-in-view@1.0.4" has
>   incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.4.2". warning " >
>   react-native-fade-in-view@1.0.4" has incorrect peer dependency
>   "react-native@^0.40.0". warning " > babel-jest@21.2.0" has unmet peer
>   dependency 
>   "babel-core@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0-alpha || ^7.0.0-beta ||
>   ^7.0.0". [4/4] Building fresh packages... Done in 6.51s.

I also updated my yarn using the following steps:
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3042
Do you have any idea what happen on my project?

Here is my total code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, AsyncStorage, Dimensions, Image, ImageBackground, Platform, ScrollView, StatusBar, TouchableHighlight, TouchableOpacity, View, Text,  TextInput } from "react-native";
import { Body, Switch, Button, Container, Content, Header, Input, InputGroup, Left, Right, StyleProvider, Title } from "native-base";
import I18n from '../../libs/i18n';
import {Config} from '../../config';
// import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import FadeInView from 'react-native-fade-in-view';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: I18n.t('Login'),
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {

    };

  }

  render() {

    if(this.timer > 0) return;
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
          //turn off the pop up
           this.props.navigation.navigate('Home_Tool');
          this.timer = null;  //not necessary if you are unmounting the component
        }, 3000);

    return (

            <Image source={require('../../assets/images/Home/tt.jpg')} style={styles.Container} >
              <View style={styles.logoContiainer}>

                  <Image source={require('../../assets/images/Home/ttt.png')} style={styles.Container} />

              </View>
            </Image>

            );


  }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  Container: {
    flex: 1,
       // remove width and height to override fixed static size
    width: null,
    height: null,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  logoContiainer: {
    flex: 0.25,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: (Dimensions.get('window').width)/2,

  },


});
```

Comment: can you post the code with the line where you get `Cannot read property 'func' of undefined`?

Comment: @IshitaSinha: Thanks for your reply, I have posted it

Comment: @IshitaSinha: I should mentioned that, when I delete the "import FadeInView from 'react-native-fade-in-view';" code, everything work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `react-native-fade-in-view` is importing propTypes from React, i don't know what version of React you are using but this is not supported anymore :

> React.PropTypes has moved into a different package since React v15.5. Please use the prop-types library instead.

As this package is just a simple React Component i suggest you to copy this component in your project then import it locally.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Animated } from "react-native";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class FadeInView extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      viewOpacity: new Animated.Value(0)
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { viewOpacity } = this.state;
    const { onFadeComplete, duration = 500 } = this.props;

    Animated.timing(viewOpacity, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration
    }).start(onFadeComplete || (() => {}));
  }

  render() {
    const { viewOpacity } = this.state;
    const { style } = this.props;

    return (
      <Animated.View style={[{ opacity: viewOpacity }].concat(style || [])}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}

FadeInView.propTypes = {
  onFadeComplete: PropTypes.func, // This was throwing error because PropTypes is undefined
  duration: PropTypes.number,
  style: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.number,
    PropTypes.string,
    PropTypes.object,
    PropTypes.array
  ]),
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.array, PropTypes.object]).isRequired
};

export default FadeInView;
```

Then make sure to have `prop-types` package in your project dependencies.

Comment: What a great answer, I have already vote it up. :) However, as I applied it on my image it does't show my image anymore.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks, It needed to put inside a View. Thanks a lot.